# Como remover acentos de todas as consoantes em javascript( Ex: ŘŔ)

Tags: node.js, regex, replace

Salve Galerinha.

Possuo um backend que recebe dados de uma aplicação mobile , porém tenho o risco de receber algumas consoantes com acento , e preciso remover acentuação somente das consoantes(Alguns vendedores acabam errando a digitação por engano). É possivel fazer isso em javascript , tem alguma forma de fazer isso em Node sem ser com vários replaces aninhados?

ex: **Ŕua Caicó -> Rua Caicó**

Comment: `'Ŕua Caicó '.normalize('NFD').replace(/(?<![aieou])\p{M}/ugi, '')`

Comment: Valeeeeu , funcionou perfeitamente.